# Keep stored procedures / UDF in separate database

Tags: sql-server, database-design

Is it good practice to keep all stored procedures in separate database which has no data and all tables with real data in separate database(s)? Main reason: to be able to upgrade stored procedures with simple restore which does not affect the production data. Second (optional) reason: 2+ databases can be processed by the same set of stored procedures.

Comment: Re reason #1, I don't think restore is a good practice for deployments. Consider DACPACs.

Comment: Don't downvote the guy just because you don't like what he is asking. Just tell him why its a bad idea people!

Comment: As well as other objections you would lose  ownership chaining and have to deal with cross database security.

Comment: I've done something similar in a weird situation, only with ad-hoc reporting views that referenced a secondary replica of an AG database. They were a mess and I didn't want them in the production database, so it worked *okay*. Definitely not best, or even good, practice and it doesn't sound like you have a strong use case for it.

Comment: I know it is not best and not be used in a big project. But for small project where all queries are in stored procedures and from time to time is necessary to do update - the alternative is to execute queries from text files with new SP changes.

Comment: @i486 it sounds like you're asking permission to do something that is a bad practice and do not like the answers provided, warning you not to hurt yourself. You won't find permission here, we are just a giant group of professionals that work in this space daily screaming at the guy on the ledge not to jump. This is horrible from a management stand point, i.e. youre hurting the company you let implement this, and it will hurt you when you have to fix it. There are more alternatives, list out the larger goal you desire, or restrictions that you are concerned with.

Comment: @i486 my apologies, I was not attacking you. There are several bad approaches, I know as I fix them often. Direct answer to 'is this frequently used', No it is not. Asking the question and the question itself isn't bad; your response to 4 other people where you defend the bad approach is why I cared enough to appeal to you. Give us more information we can assist, give us an overview as to why you thought of this approach and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I can't add an answer now. Typical app dev for any business goes one of two ways. One guy codes it all in .net and dumps strings into a database, and leverages his .net to pass tsql strings to the database with select *. The second is N guy(s) code a database with usp_ (user stored procedures) and calls the usp_ by name in the .net code. This sounds like what you are doing, and from the application layer that is very good.

Comment: Where the question breaks down, and everyone on the thread is sitting on the edge of their chair is ... WHY two databases? Table objects are unaffected by updates or re-compiling usp_. If this is a source controlled db then you simply use the SDLC to apply the changes. If not then you use SSMS to alter the usp_. What is the reason for separating the data from the DML that uses the data?

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen that approach used.  If you are keeping your database schema in a source control system, then you can generate deployment scripts.  Such tools can compare previous versions of your schema and deploy the changes.  [SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh272686(v=vs.103).aspx) is available in Visual Studio.